# Can I use iText.Layout.Element.Link to open custom URI scheme

Tags: .net, hyperlink, pdf-generation, itext7

I've been trying to implement a `Link` object in a `Paragraph` to open a custom URI scheme, using `iText7`.

For example, the following code works with the `mailto:` scheme:

```
Dim myUriOk As String = "mailto:test@test.com"
Dim linkOk As New Link("mailto", PdfAction.CreateURI(myUriOk))
paragraph.Add(linkOk)
```

When I click on the link, the default message application is opened (Gmail).

When I do the same thing with my custom scheme, nothing happens:

```
Dim myUriKo As String = "myCustomScheme:C:\Temp\Exemple.sgs"
Dim linkKo As New Link("test", PdfAction.CreateURI(myUriKo))
paragraph.Add(linkKo)
```

The link is showing in my PDF file but the application doesn't open.

When I try to open ***myCustomScheme:C:\Temp\Exemple.sgs*** in my browser, the application is correctly opening, so the configuration of my custom scheme is valid.

Maybe this isn't the best way to do it, but the goal is to open an application with a file as parameter from my PDF file (generated using iText7), and I want to know if there are any other solutions to do that?

Comment: Which URLs are supported, depends on the PDF viewer.

Comment: @mkl: I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC for the PFD vizualization. And I have implemented for the custom scheme the same model that the model used for `mailto:` scheme.